# Backup to Dropbox using Gnome Backup Tool

Tags: gnome, backup, dropbox

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and would like to Backup some folders to my Dropbox Pro account. Is there a way to use the Built-In Gnome Backup facility to do that (without installing the Dropbox client - I would like to avoid that since I don't want to sync the 200+ GB of data I have on my dropbox account). The Gnome Backup tool offers Amazon S3 and Rackspace Cloud Services for Storage location, maybe is there a way to teach it Dropbox, too (by installing some extra package). I would also be fine to configure it via WebDAV, if possible, but I'd like to avoid scripting (I know that using curl or wget it would be possible to use DropBox but I prefer to have a GUI solution .. I am too old for scripting ;) If Ubuntu Gnome 16.4 supports Dropbox backups out of the box I'd also be happy to upgrade.

Thanks for your help,

- Johannes